# ST_Contains Removes Invalid Geometry & ST_MakeValid PostGIS Query Gives Error

Tags: postgis, postgresql, query

I'm trying to query a list of polygons (geo_parcels) and get all of them, and also spatially add any points or polygons (geo_buildings) that are in or on that polygon.  Normally I'd use a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT geo_parcels.objectid
FROM geo_parcels LEFT JOIN geo_buildings ON st_contains(geo_parcels.geom, geo_buildings.geom)
WHERE (ST_IsValid(ST_MakeValid(ST_CurveToLine(geo_parcels.geom))) OR geo_parcels.geom IS NULL)
AND (ST_IsValid(ST_MakeValid(ST_CurveToLine(geo_buildings.geom))) OR geo_buildings.geom IS NULL);
```

However, that gave a new to me error of

> GEOSContains: TopologyException: side location conflict at # #. This can occur if the input geometry is invalid.

I dug around and got it working by removing the ST_MakeValid, which is surprising, but works.

```
SELECT DISTINCT geo_parcels.objectid
FROM geo_parcels LEFT JOIN geo_buildings ON st_contains(geo_parcels.geom, geo_buildings.geom)
WHERE (ST_IsValid((ST_CurveToLine(geo_parcels.geom))) OR geo_parcels.geom IS NULL)
AND (ST_IsValid((ST_CurveToLine(geo_buildings.geom))) OR geo_buildings.geom IS NULL);
```

With this, I get 23146 results.
However, If I just query the geo_parcels directly, I get 23396 results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT geo_parcels.objectid FROM geo_parcels;
```

I'd like to find a way to not remove any results when I add in the ST_Contains.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes sense, as your are joining on the raw geometry.

If a geometry is invalid but fixable, the `where` clause (`WHERE (ST_IsValid(ST_MakeValid(ST_CurveToLine(geo_parcels.geom)))`) wouldn't filter it out but the geometry remains invalid, while when you remove the `st_makevalid` the `where` clause filters out invalid geometries.

Also, because you are referencing the right table in the where clause, it is not really a left join anymore. Instead, you will want to move the restricting clause to the join condition.

The query below will keep every `geo_parcels`, even if its geometry is invalid. But since `geo_buildings` is not in the part of the `select` and is not filtering out records, you might as well just omit it..

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT geo_parcels.objectid
-- ... and possibly other fields from geo_buildings?
FROM geo_parcels 
 LEFT JOIN geo_buildings 
  ON st_contains(geo_parcels.geom, geo_buildings.geom)
    AND (ST_IsValid(geo_parcels.geom) OR geo_parcels.geom IS NULL)
    AND (ST_IsValid(geo_buildings.geom) OR geo_buildings.geom IS NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this still gives me the error:

````GEOSContains: TopologyException: side location conflict at # #. This can occur if the input geometry is invalid.````

Comment: try removing the `st_curveToLine` which has nothing to do with points or polygons

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and get it still with this (admittedly bad) dataset.

Tried this query out of curiosity but it just runs forever and gives a lot of Ring Self-Intersection Notices.
````
SELECT DISTINCT geo_parcels.objectid
-- ... and possibly other fields from geo_buildings?
FROM geo_parcels 
LEFT JOIN geo_buildings 
 ON (st_contains(geo_parcels.geom, geo_buildings.geom)
 OR geo_parcels.geom IS NULL
 OR geo_buildings.geom IS NULL);
````